# How to set correctly sizes of a jpanels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a two jpanels: jpanel1 and jpanel2 which must have correct minimal size according to their content. jpanel0 is the container for these two panels, it must be on the left side of a frame. And here is jpanel3 that should take the rest of the available space on the right side.

How to set the size of a jpanel to all available space?

My desired output:
[image]

My current output:
[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Panels {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();

    JPanel jPaneTab1 = new JPanel();
    jPaneTab1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    JPanel jpanel0 = new JPanel();
    jpanel0.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpanel0, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jpanel0.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("jpanel0"));
    jpanel0.setBackground(Color.RED);


    JPanel jpanel1 = new JPanel();
    jpanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    jpanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("jpanel1"));
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    jpanel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    JLabel jlabel1 = new JLabel("jlabel1");
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 2);
    jpanel1.add(jlabel1, gc);
    JLabel jlabel2 = new JLabel("jlabel2");
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 2);
    jpanel1.add(jlabel2, gc);


    JPanel jpanel2 = new JPanel();
    jpanel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    jpanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("jpanel2"));
    GridBagConstraints gc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    jpanel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    JLabel jlabel3 = new JLabel("jlabel3");
    gc2.gridx = 0;
    gc2.gridy = 0;
    gc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 2);
    jpanel2.add(jlabel3, gc2);
    JLabel jlabel4 = new JLabel("jlabel4");
    gc2.gridx = 0;
    gc2.gridy = 1;
    gc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 2);
    jpanel2.add(jlabel4, gc2);






    JPanel jpanel3 = new JPanel();
    jpanel3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    JLabel jlabel5 = new JLabel("jpanel3");
    jpanel3.add(jlabel5);

    jpanel0.add(jpanel1);
    jpanel0.add(jpanel2);
    jPaneTab1.add(jpanel0, BorderLayout.WEST);
    jPaneTab1.add(jpanel3, BorderLayout.CENTER);        

    JPanel jPaneTab2 = new JPanel();


    jtp.addTab("tab1", jPaneTab1);
    jtp.addTab("tab2", jPaneTab2);

    myFrame.add(jtp);       
    myFrame.setSize(800, 600);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Addition:

When I use BorderLayout for main(tab panel) I'm getting another problem:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Layouts work easier when you break down the layout into logical panels and then nest panels with different layout managers.

For example, use a panel with a `BorderLayout` as the content for the tabbed pane.

Then you create a "ride side panel" and add it to this panel and a "center panel"

```
JPanel main = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
JPanel rightSide = new JPanel( ... );
JPanel center = new JPanel(...);
main.add(rightSide, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
main.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then you set the layouts for the "rightSide" and "center" panels and add components to each of those panels.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `GridBagLayout`, `BorderLayout`, or `BoxLayout` managers. These are outdated managers from the 90s.

For instance, when you do this:

`gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 2);`

you are hardcoding pixel-width spaces between components, which
will not work across the wide variety of today's screens.

Insted, one should choose either `GroupLayout` or `MigLayout`.

Here is a working example with the `MigLayout` manager. Notice how easy
is to create the layout with this manager. (Four lines of code.) Also, we use logical pixels (lp) instead of physical pixels.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class PanelsEx extends JFrame {

    public PanelsEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JTabbedPane tabpane = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel pnl1 = createPanel("Panel 1");
        JPanel pnl2 = createPanel("Panel 2");
        JPanel pnl3 = createPanel("Panel 3");        

        mainPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("ins 10lp"));

        mainPanel.add(pnl1, "w 150lp, h 100lp, split 2, flowy, ay top");
        mainPanel.add(pnl2, "w 150lp, h 100lp");
        mainPanel.add(pnl3, "push, grow");

        tabpane.add("First", mainPanel);

        add(tabpane);

        pack();        

        setTitle("Panels");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    private JPanel createPanel(String text) {

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(text);
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.add(lbl);

        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        return pnl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            PanelsEx ex = new PanelsEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the code example]